# Java - reading data from website

Tags: java, html, xpath, w3c

I know how to read data from xml file, but i can't find any examples of reading data from website (HTML). All examples include xml files. I need do it with DOM parser or XPath. Html code:

```
<table class="tabela">
<thead>
    ....
</thead>    

<tbody>
    <tr >
        <td>...</td>
        <td class="al">WIG20</a></td>
        <td class="ar">2242.42</td>
        <td class="ar">2551.47</td>
        <td class="ar">2522,37</td>
        <td class="ar">2505,41</td>
        <td class="ar">2524,83</td>
        <td class="ar">2516,76</td>
        <td class="ar">
            <span class="r_dn">-0,32</span>
        </td>
        <td class="ar">564,34</td>
        <td class="ar">5</td>
        <td class="ar">14</td>
        <td class="ar">1</td>
        <td class="ar">17:15:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

There is any possible to read all lines from this table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSoup library](http://jsoup.org/) is designed specifically for that purpose.

Comment: I would like to avoid the use of external jar libraries.

Comment: @Tango then, you need write your own parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will probably have to use JSoup